# Best practice Typescript and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a specific question around a component that receives `{...props}` to allow for any prop to be passed in. This component only receives a string prop right now, but when it was written it wanted to allow for basically any prop to be passed in. What is the best typescript best practice to tackle this? Since you don't know what prop may be passed in? Do you only handle the specifc prop ? or is there a way for typescript to allow for ...props?

TY team :D

Comment: This somewhat defeats the goal of TypeScript outright because you no-longer know what you will be dealing with from the props.  Sometimes that's unavoidable given JavaScript, but generally you look to narrow the types down, not broaden them without limit.

Comment: Hi, what do You mean any prop ? Could you please provide an example? Do you mean that [props] could be an object with random interface?

Comment: Are you not able to use `any`?

Comment: `any` is the opposite of a best practice of typescript. `any` is anti-typescript.

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow any and all props? Are you sure there isn't a pattern? There is very likely a way to have type safety depending on what you want to do. For instance, if this component wraps another, then maybe you want infer the props from the inner component and expose on the outer component with a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best practice, as far as I know.

Let's assume your component is called `ShowAnyProps`, and it takes any props, and you don't want to enforce any limitations on what kind of props can be passed.

### The `ShowAnyProps` Component

```
type IProps = Record<string, unknown>;
export const ShowAnyProps: React.FC<IProps> (props) {
    // Use props here...
}
```

`props` is an object with string keys, but you don't know its values. Object keys are always strings, and `props` is always an object, because that's how JSX works.

Inside the component, you'll want to do some type narrowing to handle all possible kinds of values:

- `string`
- `number`

  - `NaN`
- `boolean`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `object` (and other things that are objects):

  - `array`
  - `function`
  - class instances
- `Symbol`
- `bigint`
- `Map`
- `Set`

Given the wide variation of things that can be passed in, you might want to limit the props, to only "regular" values. Maybe JSON-like values only:

```
import type { JSONValue } from 'type-fest';
type IProps = Record<string, JsonValue>;
```

### Usage of ShowAnyProps

Material-UI has a good convention. Instead of passing all props to the component, the intended props are passed on a sub-object. See [`inputProps` on `TextField`](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props), for example.

So the usage would look like this:

```
interface IProps {
    // own props
    showAnyPropsProps: Record<string, JsonValue>;
};
export const UsageComponent: React.FC<IProps> (props) {
    // ...
    return (
        <div>
            {/* ... other stuff ... */}
            <ShowAnyProps {...props.showAnyPropsProps} />
        </div>
    );
}
```